# PHP File upload, if left blank

Tags: php, file-upload

I having a bit of an issue with my file upload, it works fine and everything, but I goto update my data and I want to change everything except for the image and hit submit, I get the Invalid Image message, I am not updating the images so there is no file in the file input text box, is there a way to bypass this?

```
if (($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")){
            if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0){
                echo $_FILES["image"]["error"];
            }else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
                "../upload/CV_1_" . date("Ymd") . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);                                                                    
                $class->update($id, $text, $image);
                echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Updated!</strong></div>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Invalid Image!</strong></div>";
        }
```

What the code above does is take the file, see if its an image and if there are any errors, show them, then it moves the file into the proper folder and updates my database.

Here is the form...

```
<form action="CV.php?action=updatesubmit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $array['id']; ?>" name="id" />
<p>
<label for="text" style="vertical-align:top;">Text</label>
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="70" rows="20"><?php echo $array['text']; ?></textarea>
</p>

<p>
<label for="image">Image</label>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo $array['image']; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
</p>

</form>
```

I hope I made sense, I have a habit of tying something out, it sounds good to me but other people wont know what I am talking about.

Played with my code and this was suggested but its not working, I'm probably doing something wrong.

```
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    if (($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")){
        if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0){
            echo $_FILES["image"]["error"];
        }else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
            "../upload/CV_1_" . date("Ymd") . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);    
}
            $class->update($id, $text, $image);
            echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Updated!</strong></div>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Invalid Image!</strong></div>";
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check for an actual upload before you do ANYTHING ELSE with the upload data:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   ... got an upload ...
}
```

Comment: Im still getting the message 'Invalid Image' I will edit my question so you can see what I did

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what's coming in. Your script's got numerous OTHER problems with it, not the least of which is trusting the user to not simply do a `ren nastyvirus.exe cutekittens.jpg` before uploading the file.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `if(isset($_FILES['image']))` around the whole block. If no image is uploaded, the file entry won't be there.

Comment: False. the `['image']` entry will still exist, whether a file was uploaded or not. You have to check the `['error']` value. A 'no file uploaded' will be error code 4/UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE.

Comment: What would that look like MarcB

Answer (score 0):

It will submit if and only if image is uploaded.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] && $_FILES["file"]["error"] < 0){
    if (($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")){
                if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0){
                    echo $_FILES["image"]["error"];
                }else{
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
                    "../upload/CV_1_" . date("Ymd") . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);                                                                    
                    $class->update($id, $text, $image);
                    echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Updated!</strong></div>";
                }
            }else{
                echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Invalid Image!</strong></div>";
            }
}
?>
```

Comment: Bad idea. partial uploads will still have a tmp_name. Check `['error']` which will tell you the true status of the upload.